# php split string by paragraph doesn't work

Tags: php, split, explode

I'm having some troubles splitting a string by paragraphs.

I have a string inside `$item->description`, but it doesn't seems to be doing what I need.

My code:

```
$text = explode("</p>", $item->description);
var_dump($text);
```

It's outputing only the positions with all text, not doing the split:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(726) "<b>Requirements</b> <p>A zeal towards learning to learn 
as a priority. A sound knowledge of Internet and Browsing!</p> <b>Description</b> <p>The 
course DIGITAL SKILLS FOR TEACHERS inherits the requirements for being a ROCKSTAR 
Teachers with competency towards excellence within classrooms on narration with experience 
and making a wow feature a continuous activity in classrooms on priority. The course 
modules the expertise to imbibe for all teachers towards excellence with the adoption 
of technology in a big very way!</p> <b>Who is the target audience?</b> <p>Any individual 
who feels teaching is Sharing. A must for all Educators.</p>" }
```

Anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: https://3v4l.org/mB7YW Unable to reproduce

Comment: Works for me when I test it

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Could the text be UTF-8?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using version 7.2.5 and checked the string and it's gives me as ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one :-

```
$text = $item->description ;
$arr = explode("</p>", $text);
echo "<br>".$arr[0] ;
```

Hope it will not come out with any issue .

Comment: This solution will come the same output as my main question.

Comment: Did you run it ? Please check it once more and let me know .

Comment: Yes I run it. Maybe there's something with my code elsewhere that is not going good. Maybe will do another show more/less instead.

Comment: Can you echo item->description string just before explode and check the result ?

Comment: Echoing item->description returns the plain text.

Comment: And what is the output of the code I have written ?

Comment: It's the same output as I stated in my initial question. I'm already searching for JS a function show more/less that works with HTML decode.

Comment: When I'm testing here it is only displaying the first sentence up to the end of the paragraph . Are you taking my three lines of codes that I have written ? Are you using "echo" as I have mentioned in my 3rd statement ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the plain text then you can use the [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function. It will remove all the html tags from your text including paragraph tags.

For example:

```
/** Replace the <b> tag with placeholder */
$text = str_replace("<b>", "$", $item->description);
/** Replace the <\b> tag with placeholder */
$text = str_replace("<\b>", "^", $item->description);
/** Remove html from the text */
$text = strip_tags($text);
/** Replace placeholder with <b> tag */
$text = str_replace("$", "<b>", $item->description);
/** Replace placeholder with <\b> tag */
$text = str_replace("^", "<\b>", $item->description);
```

Alternately you can use the [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function. It will extract all text between paragraph tags. For example:

```
/** The text between paragraph tags is extracted using regular expression */
preg_match_all("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/iU", $item->description, $matches);
/** Each element of $text array contains text within a paragraph */
$text  = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this format:-

```
$text = explode(PHP_EOL, $item->description);
```

Hope this will work .

Comment: You have not checked my code and the actual text and have given a negative response . The text uploaded here has new line within the double codes besides "p" tag , means there are more new lines than number of paragraphs . So correct the text within double quotes and check with my code again .

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code too :-

```
$text = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $item->description) ;
echo $text[0] ;
```

Comment: My guess would be that either thay are not interested as these would be ignored in HTML or they will later want to remove the newlines and not split anything on the newlines

Comment: Yes. The objetive here is to create a simple "preview". And the preview should be visible until the end of the first paragraph. Can't really see why it's not working :(

Comment: I don't know why you are giving a negative response to my correct solution . Please check my update and check you will get the required output .